# drupal email date token add 24 hours to current date

Tags: drupal

Im sending a one time password reset link to a user via email. The text is as below:

> Hi username,
>
> We are sending you a temporary link that is valid for 24 hours only until <>

I need to add 24 hrs to the [current-date:long] token.

Also it needs to be added in the account settings E-mails.

Comment: Any help on this please?

Comment: please show what you've tried so far and why it's not working

Comment: I wanted to know how to approach this ,in terms of creating a new module or any inbuilt functions etc...

Comment: You probably need to create your own custom token, or extend the existing [current-date]. Or create a date field with expire date and use it as token, otherwise do it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a custom module which sends an email with tomorows date